# Когда использовать commit, push?

Tags: git

Изучаю git но так не могу понять, когда коммитеть, а когда пушить. Представим, что вам дали листочек с заданием «Написать функцию, которая будет считать числа. Написать класс на обработку данных из базы» когда вы будете использовать commit, push?

Так же, представим вы верстаете макете с использованием react, когда нужно тут commit, push (для себя верстаешь)?

Comment: Невозможно в данном случае дать конкретный ответ. "commit" связан с сохранением изменений локально в вашем репозитории, тогда как "push" связан с отправкой этих локальных изменений на удаленный сервер для совместной работы и синхронизации с другими разработчиками.

Comment: если знать, что такое коммит и пуш, то вопрос не возникнет. Коммиты можно делать без пуша, а пуш без предварительных коммитов - никак. Поэтому вопрос "когда будете делать коммит, а когда пуш" - не имеет практического смысла.

Comment: https://askanydifference.com/ru/difference-between-commit-and-push/

Comment: Почему невозможно дать ответ? Вот когда вы работаете, в каких случаях вы коммитете?

Comment: Может вы коммитете когда какие-то функцию написали. Пушить нужно когда выполнил задание какое-то?

Comment: Невозможно дать ответ потому, что не существует единственно правильного ответа. Если Вы работаете в команде, то пушить  будете тогда, когда это определено правилами команды. Коммитить, возможно,  тогда, когда удобно Вам. А если Вы работаете один, тем более если это пет-проект, так и вовсе все определяется Вами - когда хотите, тогда и делайте. Рано или поздно Вы найдете удобный для себя вариант.

Comment: И коммитить и пушить можно хоть после каждой новой буквы, хоть только в раз в месяц. Нет никакого "нужно". Почитай наконец, что это такое и в чем разница.

Answer (score -1):

> когда вы будете использовать commit, push?

Закоммитить - это значит сохранить изменения из вашей рабочей папки (точнее, из индекса, но сейчас эти детали не важны) в вашем локальном репозитории гита.

Делать это имеет смысл тогда, когда вы внесли набор изменений, которому можно дать осмысленное название (и записать его в коммент коммита).
Тогда у вас каждый коммит будут представлять логически законченный шаг вашей разработки, что позже поможет разбираться в вашем "творчестве" и искать нужную правку.
То есть, правило такое: *Один коммит реализует какую-то одну законченную мини-задачу*.
Получится осмысленное среднее между "закоммитить всё подряд что накодил за день" и "коммитить после каждой строчки".

Запушить - это значит открыть коллегам (а также CI/CD) доступ к вашим коммитам.
Обычно пушить надо, когда вы сделали свою часть задачи и протестировали её, и коллеги могут начинать делать их часть работы, опираясь на вашу часть.
Если вы единственный разработчик, то пушить надо когда вы готовы отдать ваши коммиты в автосборку и автодеплой проекта.